# Why is ldrexd used instead of ldrd for MSVC std::atomic?

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, arm, stdatomic

MSVC defines `__ldrexd` intrinsic for 32-bit ARM. It emits `ldrexd` instruction.
MSVC also defines `__iso_volatile_load64` intrinsic for everything. It emits `ldrd` intruction on 32-bit ARM.

MSVC makes special case for 32-bit ARM to use precisely `__ldrexd` instead of `__iso_volatile_load64`, see [the implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/c10ae01b4d9508eed9d5f059a120ee7223b6ac12/stl/inc/atomic#L827-L838):

```
    _NODISCARD _Ty load() const noexcept { // load with sequential consistency
        const auto _Mem = _Atomic_address_as<long long>(_Storage);
        long long _As_bytes;
#ifdef _M_ARM
        _As_bytes = __ldrexd(_Mem);
        _Memory_barrier();
#else
        _As_bytes = __iso_volatile_load64(_Mem);
        _Compiler_or_memory_barrier();
#endif
        return reinterpret_cast<_Ty&>(_As_bytes);
    }
```

In which cases `__ldrexd` is better than `__ldrd`?

Comment: ldrexd vs ldrd is clearly defined in the arm documentation and what it does.  ldrex is not better than, it has a special purpose, it leaves or keeps the domain being accessed in an exclusive access domain.  and then following it by a memory barrier is interesting.  I have seen ldrex/strex misunderstood and incorrectly used so it might be a case of that here or this is part of a combination of things with a specific purpose.  both will perform a 64 bit aligned read.  as documented one sets exclusive access the other doesnt. (assuming these functions/defines become the actual instruction)

Comment: what part of the arm documentation did you not understand.  the armv7-a docs do a better job on the software side than armv6.  but you want to get the axi documentation to see what the real difference is and what the hardware requirements (chip vendor or arm's l1 cache, etc) are for exclusive access vs not.  also easily availble on arms website.

Comment: @old_timer, from the documentation it does not follow that using `ldrexd` here makes sense at all, so I'm seeking the truth outside. (I'm also not developing for arm, I just interested in it, as in what I may need support in the future in my code)

Comment: it doesnt make sense to me either.  What did microsoft say about it?

Comment: No answer so far. And moreover: `strexd` is not even available as an intrinsic, so `__ldrexd` is apparently exposed for this usage

Comment: that doesnt make sense ...

Comment: @old_timer, I think I found an insteresting comment on this: https://community.arm.com/developer/ip-products/processors/f/cortex-a-forum/5474/strd-atomic/13023